# Django: How to enable users to delete their account

Tags: python, django

I am unsure of what went wrong but I still cannot delete my own account.

I am just redirected to a home page.

Views.py

```
def delete_user(request, username):

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username = username)
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'

    else:
        context['msg'] = 'Request method should be "DELETE"!'

    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
from account.views import (
    delete_user,
)

 path('delete/<username>', delete_user, name='delete_account'),
```

account.html

```
      <form action="{% url 'account:delete_account' username=request.user.username %}" method="GET">
  <a class="mt-4 btn btn-danger deleteaccount" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account')" href="">Delete Account</a> 
</form>
```

Comment: in your first view, you don't need kwargs.get(user__id). just delete that line

Comment: And try it again without that line

Comment: Hi please refer to the updated codes, nope it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First if you want to delete user who logged in, you don't need to pass it in argument. Just called it in your function `request.user`
2. I tried your code with some little modification like code below (just for testing). It works. User will be deleted. Paste this code and try it with postman. I don't know with your project, but make sure your method DELETE request working properly. According to the HTML standard, the valid methods for form are GET and POST. So you can't do like this `<form method="delete">`. However Django correct handle 'PUT' and 'DELETE' (and all others) http methods.You can make PUT and DELETE http calls thought the ajax.

Just for testing, call in Postman with DELETE method `localhost:8000/delete/user1`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.


@csrf_exempt
def delete_user(request, username):
    
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user.delete()
            return HttpResponse('Bye bye')
        except Exception as e: 
            return HttpResponse('Something went wrong!')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request method should be "DELETE"!')



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('delete/<username>', delete_user)
]
```

Note: I skip CSRF_TOKEN validation with `@csrf_exempt`

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i did not use a form though in my html, i simply used the <a>

Comment: I tried to do "call in Postman with DELETE method localhost:8000/delete/testuser1" and i got " page not found"

Comment: Sorry, you should change localhost:8000 with your running django website. In case you run locally on port 8000 (by default that way django running) run like that `localhost:8000\delete\user1` make sure you add user1 first from admin

Comment: If you call using <a> you should use AJAX then. You can google it how to do that. But, if you are in hurry, test first your DELETE routing using postman like I said

Comment: hi yes i did that and i got page not found. does this mean the delete is not working

Comment: ohhh so i will require the <form> element for it to work? then for the form would i require the csrf token?

Comment: yes. both request from FORM or AJAX you should use CSRF_TOKEN. That is standard security.

Comment: I have edited my code to the above but it still doesnt work, kindly refer to the edited version. I'm starting to think either my laptop is spoilt or the delete function isnt working? i tried to do http://127.0.0.1/8000/delete\user1 and got redirected back to homefeed page

Comment: 8000 is port. Check it carefully `localhost:8000\delete\user1` :)

Comment: Make sure. You create user1 beside admin user, okay. Then call that link. Then your user1 will be deleted

Comment: ok this is just not really working, i will figure out myself why later. actually have anothe rpressing question that really hope you could help too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516934/django-query-error-how-do-i-properly-query-my-total-likes-to-show-in-the-home-s

Comment: You type like this `127.0.0.1/8000/delete/user1` it should be like this `127.0.0.1:8000/delete/user1`.

Comment: yep it doesnt work, basically i will be directed back to my homefeed page, all the blog posts will disappear, but when i refresh page it will come back again

Comment: Well to make it works. 
(1) First you create new django project. 
(2) migrate and create new user 
(3) login to admin 
(4) create another user, let say user1 
(5) Now you have two users. 
(6) Before testing delele link, add code above 
(7) Test link with type `127.0.0.1:8000/delete/user1` in postman with *DELETE* method. Make sure you know how to set DELETE method in POSTMAN.
(8) After calling that link, your user1 will be deleted.

I hope that will help :)

Comment: The line of `User.objects.get(username=username)` is not secure. With that anyone can delete any user. Instead use `request.user`. Secondly: excepting CSRF also a security problem while session or basic authentication mechanism are active.

Comment: Yes. It is not good practice for security. It will be improved after this guy problem solved which is unable to delete a user.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just inactivate the user do not delete user. So user can not log in again while inactive.

While you want user delete itself, not anyone else. get user directly from request. No need to url.

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}
    
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            user = request.user
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'

    else:
        context['msg'] = 'Request method should be "DELETE"!'

    return render(request, 'template.html', context=context)
```

The path should looks like

```
path('account/delete', delete_user, name='delete_account'),
```

Note: Request should be `DELETE` not `GET` or `POST`

Comment: Hi ishak, thanks for the reply. I have edited my code to fit your suggestion but it did not work out, pls refer to the post and see the error I got