# Django Query Error: How do i properly query my total likes to show in the Home Screen?

Tags: python, django, querying

Can anyone advise on how to query the `total_likes of a post to be shown in my HTML, I tried, but was given this error:

```
Page not found (404)
No BlogPost matches the given query.
```

THANK YOU!

I think it might be the way I am querying and linking the blog post with the likes but I'm not sure why I'm wrong and I don't know how to modify it despite trying for a few hours.

views.py

```
def home_feed_view(request, **kwargs):
    
    context = {}

    blog_posts = sorted(BlogPost.objects.all(), key= attrgetter('date_updated'), reverse = True)
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=request.POST.get('blog_post_slug'))
    total_likes = blog_post.total_likes()
    liked = False
    if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts 
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post
    context['total_likes'] = total_likes
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)


def LikeView(request, slug):
    context = {}

    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True 
    return redirect('HomeFeed:detail', slug=slug)
```

.html

```html
{% for post in blog_posts %} 

<td class="table-primary">

  <form action="{% url 'HomeFeed:like_post' post.slug %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} 

    <button type="submit" name="blog_post_slug"  value="{{post.slug}}" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>
      Like
    </button> 

    {{ total_likes }} Likes

  </form>

</td>   

{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from HomeFeed.views import(
    home_feed_view,
    LikeView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_feed_view , name= "main"),
    path('<slug>/like/', LikeView, name='like_post'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception: `Page not found (404) No BlogPost matches the given query.` is being raised by `get_object_or_404` as it does exactly what the name says. If the `BlogPost` with the supplied `slug` in any of the views doesn't exist in the database, Django will raise an `Http404` exception as you're witnessing.

Now, since we don't know the structure of your `BlogPost` model, I can't really tell you where to change, all I can tell you is you need to make sure, the `slug` is a unique field on each `BlogPost` instance, othwerwise your code is working as one would expect.

**EDIT**

I had not seen the `BlogPost` model, my bad, but the information is still relavant a BlogPost with such a `slug` does not exist. So do a manual check, see what the slug arrives in the view(s) as, and then check manually either in DB or in your shell.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I have included models.py in the code if will help

Comment: Then do a manual check, as I suggested. There is nothing wrong with this line `post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)` if the slug is valid.

Comment: Hi Redgren, after about 1hr of trying i still cant get the correct blogpost query, possible to maybe show how I should solve it? :( I really cant figure out how to reference the blog post without adding extra arguments to the function.

Comment: Are you familiar with generic class based views in Django?

Comment: thanks for the input redgren! sorry im noob and still learning generic class after you told me about it so im still unable to solve my problem..meanwhile i have made another post to see if there are others ways to do it. i tried to change `slug=request.POST.get('blog_post_slug')` to `slug=slug` like how i queried the other blogposts, but i got a name error that says slug is not defined. and i know thats because i cant put slug as an argument in the function itself. even if like what you said There is nothing wrong with this line post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug), i just cant query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531067/django-nameerror-slug-is-not-defined I have included the detail blog view to show how i managed to query it for the detailed version of the blog. If you have some time pls kindly have a look :) otherwise thank you