# Django Views, having 2 redirects in 1 view

Tags: python, django, view

Is it possible to have 2 redirect() in the same django view. so when the like button is in the home page, i want it to redirect back to home page, if like button is in detail page, i want to redirect back to detail page?

For instance:

```
def LikeView(request, slug):
    context = {}
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    post.likes.add(request.user)

    if in homepage:
        return redirect('HomeFeed:detail', slug=slug)
    
    else:
        return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
```

```
def delete_blog_view(request,slug):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    #YOU WANT to check if user is authenticated. if not, you need to authenticate! redirect you to that page
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("must_authenticate")

    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    blog_post.delete()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': account.pk }))
```

Comment: Yes, why would that be impossible? But the `if in homepage` is an invalid condition.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you advise how I can do that, as I have not done it before, i searched but could not find any results. thank you so much

Comment: well exactly what are you trying to check?

Comment: ok so its a blog post app, the post can be seen from the home page and also their own private post page, every post have their like button, and so when i press on the like button in the home page i want to redirect it to the home page, when i press it in their own private page i want it to be redirected into their own private page

Comment: I had some problem like this. I had a twitter clone and when user deleted the tweet I wanted to return to their last page. I used javascript XMLHttpRequest. And after the request was properly responded from server. I use window.location.href=document.referrer; to go back to page user came from. I hope this helps your problem

Comment: you can use `return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''))` to redirect to the same page you were on or home page if the previous doesn't exist

Comment: @Mojtaba ohhh thanks for the input. you didnt try to redirect 2 times? not sure if you encountered this problem as well..i got downvoted and i think it might have been a stupid question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516934/django-query-error-how-do-i-properly-query-my-total-likes-to-show-in-the-home-s

Comment: @SLDem thank you so much for the contribution! ill check it out...currently trying to solve another problem too :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516934/django-query-error-how-do-i-properly-query-my-total-likes-to-show-in-the-home-s

Comment: @SLDem is that code itself sufficient, do i need to do any configuration to tell them how to return to the home page if it does not exist?

Comment: the second part inside the second round brackets here `('HTTP_REFERER', '' <-this)` is where it will redirect if no page is found so its self sufficient yes

Comment: @SLDem Thank you! Have a blessed year ahead :)

Comment: You too my friend :)

Comment: @kknam actually I had no idea it was possible to do it the way you want to do it. Your question also helped me to change my code and check the other answers given to your question.

Comment: hi @SLDem just wondering, if the page i want to redirect to is my account page and i need to reference it, can i just do it as : ('HTTP_REFERER', ' account:view ', user_id=account.pk) thank you

Comment: try using `reverse` like  `('HTTP_REFERER', reverse('account:view', kwargs={'user_id': account.pk }))`

Comment: @SLDem bro i edited my code to show you the full view, dk why they tell me i need to define user_id

Comment: haha thanks to you i could solve other problems as well

Comment: any idea how to define the user_id? i tried  user_id = kwargs.get("user_id") but it didnt work out lol

Comment: check my comment again, I'm using a `reverse` to get the url, you just passed the url mate :) Happy New Year btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the redirect URL in a `next` URL param. Like so:

```html
<!-- In homepage template -->
<a href="{% url 'link-to-like-view' %}?next=/home/">Like</a>

<!-- in Detail template -->
<a href="{% url 'link-to-like-view' %}?next=/detail/">Like</a>
```

or simply:

```html
<a href="{% url 'link-to-like-view' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Like</a>
```

To always pass the current URL as the redirect URL.

And then in your `LikeView`:

```py
def LikeView(request, slug):
    ...
    next = request.GET.get("next", None)
    
    if next and next != '':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to=next)
    
    # Then have a default redirect URL in case `next` wasn't passed in URL (Home for Example):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to="/home")
```

As mentioned in the Django Docs, this isn't safe (for most apps), so you have to check if URL is safe then redirect to `next` otherwise just return a default safe in-app URL.

Read on the `url_has_allowed_host_and_scheme` function to check if URL is safe on [this Docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/utils/http/)

Comment: wow this looks quite complex, thanks and I'll try it out!! Do you think you can solve this problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516934/django-query-error-how-do-i-properly-query-my-total-likes-to-show-in-the-home-s