# Django: NameError: Slug is not defined

Tags: python, django

Can anyone advise on how to query the `total_likes of a post to be shown in my HTML, I tried, but was given this error:

```
NameError: Slug is not defined
```

An expert has suggested me to use generic class views which i am not familiar with, is there any other ways i can query the correct post and define the slug? Unsure of why it didnt work for the home feed view but it did work for the detail blog view. Whats wrong actually. I cant include a slug argument in the home view as the url does not contain a . is there really no other way to do it?

views.py

```
def home_feed_view(request, slug=None):
    context = {}
    blog_posts = sorted(BlogPost.objects.all(), key= attrgetter('date_updated'), reverse = True)

    if slug:
        blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        total_likes = blog_post.total_likes()
        context['total_likes'] = total_likes
        liked = False
        if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts 

    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)


def LikeView(request, slug):
    context = {}

    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True 
    return redirect('HomeFeed:detail', slug=slug)
```

.html

```html
{% for post in blog_posts %} 

   <td class="table-primary">
       <form action="{% url 'HomeFeed:like_post' post.slug %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 
        {% if liked %}
           <button type="submit" name="mysubmitbuttonname"  value="{{post.slug}}" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Unlike</button> 
           {% else %}
           <button type="submit" name="mysubmitbuttonname"  value="{{post.slug}}" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Like</button> 
           {% endif %}
           {{ total_likes }}  Like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}

        </form>
    </td>  
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from HomeFeed.views import(
    home_feed_view,
    LikeView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_feed_view , name= "main"),
    path('<slug>/like/', LikeView, name='like_post'),
]
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/HomeFeed/views.py", line 81, in home_feed_view
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
NameError: name 'slug' is not defined
```

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem shared :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in fact i tried to do  `blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=request.POST.get('blog_post_slug'))` instead of `blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)` but then i was not able to query the blog post, and got a 404 error. Idk how to use generic class views too.. any idea how i can properly query the slug?

Comment: your `home_feed_view` has no `slug` parameter, hence it can not work with that...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep i managed to figure that out previously, is there no way I can query that if I dont use generic django class views. Because i have not learnt a lot on generic django class views

Comment: because if i have a slug parameter in my home_feed_view i will also need to have a slug in my url, which would be quite weird for a homepage?

Comment: Why do you need a single post's slug on a view you want to list all posts?

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt thanks for coming! :))  i dont need a single post slug, i am trying to query the total likes for the individual blog posts in the home page. cause i want to display the likes each post has

Comment: @hoehoehoe Since you are submit button has a  value ,you can define slug as `slug=request.POST["mysubmitbuttonname"] or "mycatchvalue"`

Comment: thanks for coming @Mugoma! your solution will generate a MultiValueDictKeyError at /HomeFeed/ error because the button is part of a loop

Comment: this is because there are many blog posts queried and each block post has their own like button and number of likes to be queried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a solution that uses class based views, to show you how clearer they are (no boilerplate code)

`urls.py`

```py
from .views import LikeView, PostDetailView, HomeFeedView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("home/", HomeFeedView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("like-post/<str:post_slug>/", LikeView.as_view(), name="like_post"),
    path("post-detail/<str:post_slug>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
]
```

Then in your `views.py`

```py
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class HomeFeedView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html"
    context_object_name = "blog_posts"
    ordering = ("-date_updated",)


class LikeView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=kwargs["post_slug"])
        # If you get a 404 error here, then your `slug` is not valid.
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            self.post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            self.post.likes.add(request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("HomeFeed:post_detail", kwargs={"post_slug": self.post.slug}))

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "HomeFeed/detail_blog.html"
    context_object_name = "blog_post"
    slug_url_kwarg = "post_slug"
    slug_field = "slug"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = self.object
        context.update({
            "total_likes": post.total_likes,
            "liked": self.request.user in post.likes.all(),
        })
        return context
```

And to factor in the change(s) in your HTML snippet:

```html
<!-- Template -->

{% for post in blog_posts %}
    <!-- Other markup-->
    <a href="{% url 'HomeFeed:post_detail' post.slug %}">View Post</a>
    <a href="{% url 'HomeFeed:like_post' post.slug %}">Like Post</a>
    <!-- Other markup -->
{% endfor %}
```

Then to show total likes etc, only do that in your template(s). For checking if user liked a certain post, use templatetags/filters that will enable you to say for example, while looping:

```html
{% with post|liked_by:user as liked %}
    <!-- 'liked' will be a bool, then do whatever you want with it.
{% endwith %}
```

This is one way to do it, but not the best way. You might also need to look that up (whether user liked post or not) using annotations on the queryset so that all the logic(especially the kind that involves a queries to the database) is handled at view level, not inside templates.

Comment: Thanks you Redgren, I will venture into generic class views as well as what you have written. Truly appreciate the code, it will help me a lot when i start practicing to write them. have a gd day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `home_feed_view`  isn't designed to take another parameter("slug")

You could have(based on your form's action attribute):

**views.py**

```
def home_feed_view(request, slug=None):
    
    context = {}
    ...
    if slug:
        blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
        ## add blogpost to content only if it exists
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        total_likes = blog_post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context['total_likes'] = total_likes

    ...
```

Comment: Hi Mugoma, thanks for the input, i have tried the code but unfortunately it says that local variable 'blog_post' and 'total_likes' has been referenced before assignment. as such i shifted     `context['blog_post'] = blog_post` and 'context['total_likes'] = total_likes` above the code. The error disappeared but i was unable to query the total likes. The like button also didnt change to unlike when i pressed on it

Comment: Check edits. However , i see you found an answer